# Could not create a cucumber expression for scenario step

Tags: java, regex, spring, cucumber

I have run into a problem that my custom cucumber configuration **works in the same test project**, but **doesn't work as a dependency in other test project**

**CustomTypeRegistry class:**

```
public class CustomTypeRegistry {

    @ParameterType("customEx\\([0-9]+\\)")
    public Integer custom(String original) {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
}
```

**Java glue step:**

```
@When("generate {custom} for test")
public void testStep(int randomNumber) {
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
}
```

**Scenario step:**

```
When generate customEx(5) for test
```

When I create tests in the same project where cucumber configurations are present this works perfectly.

When I pack project to a jar and add it as dependency to another test project it recognizes the step but in runtime I got the error:

> 17-11-2021 14:15:55.592 [main] ERROR io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.log - Exception while
> executing pickle
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could
> not create a cucumber expression for 'generate {custom} for test'.
> It appears you did not register a parameter type.
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:93)
> at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
> at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
> Caused by: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not create a cucumber
> expression for 'generate {custom} for test'.
> It appears you did not register a parameter type.
> at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.registerTypeInConfiguration(StepExpressionFactory.java:101)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.crateExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:95)
> at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.createExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:61)
> at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.createExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:49)
> at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.lambda$prepareGlue$3(CachingGlue.java:244)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
> at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.prepareGlue(CachingGlue.java:243)
> at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:68)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:199)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1631)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
> ... 2 common frames omitted
> Caused by: io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.UndefinedParameterTypeException: Undefined parameter type {custom}. Please register a ParameterType for {custom}.
> at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpression.processParameters(CucumberExpression.java:103)
> at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpression.(CucumberExpression.java:35)
> at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.ExpressionFactory.createExpression(ExpressionFactory.java:34)
> at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.crateExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:88)

*Cucumber version:* 6.8.1

*Build tool: Maven*

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason you can observe such behavior is that there is a thing called "glue path" that is basically a package where Cucumber looks up the code (including custom parameter definitions).

By default cucmber uses glue path taken as the package that contains your runner class. So I assume that when you were having your code in original project that condition was met.

But when you made a library and used it as a dependency in another project Cucumber stopped seeing that since conditions stopped being met.

You need to specify glue path manually like it is mentioned in cucumber docs

> By default Cucumber-JVM will search in the package (or sub-packages) of the runner class. You can also tell Cucumber-JVM explicitly which packages (and sub-packages) to search, with:

```
 @CucumberOptions(glue = {"<package>", "<package>", "<etc>"})
 public class RunCucumberTest{}
```